# add variables to a JavaScript event call?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myspace" class="thing"></div>
<div id="mytable" class="thing"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('my'+this).on('click', function(){
     document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = 'Chosen';
});
```

The logic is that there are two boxes, first being `myspace`, second being `mytable`. Upon clicking one of either, the box's innerHTML will read `"Chosen"`.

Basically, I would like to see if I can avoid having to write multiple click events and/or if statements.

JSFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/7cLu9uah/

Comment: It's possible to do what you're trying to do, but without more information from you, it's hard to provide an answer for the environment you're working in, as it appears to be non-standard.

Comment: `document.getElementById('my'+this).on` - won't even work, for a single element as `on` is not the correct DOM method to add an event; if using jQuery it's as simple as selecting multiple elements before adding the handler: `$("#myspace, #mytable").on(..)` (In contrast to `getElementById` which returns a single element at most, jQuery is designed to work with a set of nodes which is what the result of a `$(..)` - a jQuery object - represents.)

Comment: In my specific instance I am using a d3 library, so yes my syntaxes got crossed as I am trying to see how best to arrange my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with delegated event handling by attaching a common event handler to a parent and then operate on the clicked on item from the one click handler.

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Chosen';
});
```

```css
.thing {width: 100px; height: 20px; background:red; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="myspace" class="thing"></div>
<div id="mytable" class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

---

Also, in your code, you were trying to use `.on()` on a DOM element.  That does not work.  Perhaps you were confusing plain Javascript with jQuery which does have a `.on()` method.

And, `document.getElementById()` takes a string which should match the id of the element you are trying to find.  Your code  `ocument.getElementById('my'+this)` is not a proper usage.

---

DOM manipulations like this are often simpler using the jQuery library and you seem to be attempting to use some jQuery syntax with `.on()`.  Here's what you could do in jQuery:

```js
$(".thing").on("click", function() {
    this.innerHTML = "chosen";
})
```

```css
.thing {width: 100px; height: 20px; background:red; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myspace" class="thing"></div>
<div id="mytable" class="thing"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems here:

1. DOM elements have no `on` function. There's an `on` function in jQuery and some other libraries, but not in the DOM. `getElementById` returns a DOM element.
2. This line tries to use `this` as an ID:

   > ```
   > document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = 'Chosen';
   > ```

   While it's impossible to say without knowing what `on` you're trying to use, in the overwhelming majority of libs, in an event handler hooked up in that way, `this` refers to the **element**, not its ID. So:

   ```
   this.innerHTML = 'Chosen';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class selector:

```
function clickHandler(e) { 
   // `this` keyword refers to the clicked element
   this.textContent = 'chosen';
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.thing'), function(el) {
   el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

In case that you have several elements with `thing` class name and you don't want to attach a click handler to them you can change the selector to: `'#mytable, #myspace'`.